# recursively scan tree in parallel in golang

Tags: multithreading, recursion, go, parallel-processing, tree

I have a binary tree that accessing a node is relatively fast, with the exception of the leaves - they might be 100-1000 times slower. I have a recursive algorithm that I would like to implement in go (I am new to it).

Because I have to get to the leaves to get benefits from the parallelism I need to parallelize the execution higher in the tree. This though might result in millions of goroutines. Limiting this with semaphore does not seem the 'go' way- there is no such sync primitive. Another concern I have is how expensive is, in fact, a channel, should I use wait group instead.

My tree is abstract and the algorithm runs over it identifying the items by level and index.

```
// l3               0
//               /    \
// l2          0        1
//           /  \     /   \
// l1       0    1   2     3
//         / \  / \ / \   / \
// l0     0  1 2  3 4 5  6  7
```

For example, I can use such to compute sum of all items in a vector with the function:

```
func Sum(level, index int, items []int) int {
    if level == 0 {return items[index]}
    return Sum(level-1, index*2, items) + Sum(level-1, index*2+1, items)
}
```

What should be my approach? Can someone point me to a recursive tree multithreaded algorithm implemented in go?

Comment: It would help answer the question if you show the definition of your tree. I'm not sure what you mean by the leaves being slower.

Comment: @Logiraptor It is not my case, but image file system and you doing operation over a file - say compute a hash. Going over the directories is way cheaper that working on the leaves. Else my tree is abstract - I do not preserve it. I just use level, index to identify the item.

Comment: Can you please accept my answer or comment on why it doesn't solve your problem? :)

Comment: @Logiraptor - I am sorry, but there is probably an obvious line from what you provided as an answer and my question, but I do not see it. I cannot simply queue leafs. Consider the sum example I give, how it fits in your solution?

Comment: You're right, the hard part is traversing the tree, and @Logiraptor's answer completely punts on that.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a worker pool. Here's an example I just wrote: https://play.golang.org/p/NRM0yyQi8X

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Leaf struct {
    // Whatever
}

func worker(i int, wg *sync.WaitGroup, in <-chan Leaf) {
    for leaf := range in {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 500)
        fmt.Printf("worker %d finished work: %#v\n", i, leaf)
    }
    fmt.Printf("worker %d exiting\n", i)
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    var jobQueue = make(chan Leaf)
    var numWorkers = 10
    // the waitgroup will allow us to wait for all the goroutines to finish at the end
    var wg = new(sync.WaitGroup)
    for i := 0; i < numWorkers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go worker(i, wg, jobQueue)
    }

    // enqueue work (this goes inside your tree traversal.)
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        jobQueue <- Leaf{}
    }

    // closing jobQueue will cause all goroutines to exit the loop on the channel.
    close(jobQueue)
    // Wait for all the goroutines to finish
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't super clear, but I think the children need to be processed before the parent (as evidenced by the `Sum` example in his question), then this approach has an implicit race condition in which a child node might be in-process by one goroutine while another goroutine pulls its parent off of the channel and begins processing it (especially likely given the problem stipulates that leaf nodes are cheap compared to parent nodes).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest reading this excellent blog post from top to bottom:

https://blog.golang.org/pipelines

It covers not only an example of ***exactly*** what you need (i.e. [parallelized file-tree walk calculating MD5 file checksums](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines/parallel.go)), but ***much much*** more:

> - fan-in/fan-out channel techniques
> - parallelism
> - pipeline cancellations via *done* channels
> - pipeline error chaining via *error* channels
> - bounded parallelism

The last topic, **bounded parallelism**, is used to ensure 'walking' large-node directory-trees do not create excessive go-routines: [bounded.go](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines/bounded.go)